# Error installing anything on Ubuntu 22.10 with “sudo apt” command in the terminal: “The package code needs to be reinstalled.”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I cannot install anything with Sudo apt in terminal. I specifically tried installing java jdk and still got the error below.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: Google brings up [this QA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it).

Comment: Try this first: https://askubuntu.com/a/1277465/1210606